# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

I tried to fetch this [CSV-File](http://data.linz.gv.at/katalog/population/abstammung/2012/auslg_2012.csv) with `Net::HTTP`.

```
File.open(file, "w:UTF-8") do |f|
  content = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
  f.write(content)
end
```

After reading my local csv file again, i got some weird output.

> Nationalit\xE4t;Alter 0-5

I tried to encode it to UTF-8, but got the error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`

The [rchardet](https://github.com/oleander/rchardet) gem tolds me the content is `ISO-8859-2`. But convert to `UTF-8` will not work.

After open it in a normal Texteditor, i see it normal encoded.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can go with `force_encoding`:

```
require 'net/http'

url = "http://data.linz.gv.at/katalog/population/abstammung/2012/auslg_2012.csv"
File.open('output', "w:UTF-8") do |f|
  content = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
  f.write(content.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
end
```

But this will make you lose some acentuation in your .cvs file

If you are deadly sure that you always will use this URL as input, and the file will always keep this encoding, you can do

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'net/http'

url = "http://data.linz.gv.at/katalog/population/abstammung/2012/auslg_2012.csv"
File.open('output', "w:UTF-8") do |f|
  content = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
  f.write(content.encode("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15"))
end
```

But this will only work to this file.